# apt-get install fails aas root inside podman container

Tags: docker, apt, apt-get, podman

My Dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM python:3-ubuntu20.04
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

ENV ON_DOCKER=1

RUN echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://webproxy.ecorp.com:8080/\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt.conf
RUN echo "Acquire::https::Verify-Peer \"false\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt.conf
RUN echo "Acquire::https::Verify-Host \"false\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt.conf

RUN apt-get update -y --allow-insecure-repositories
# RUN sleep 10
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y -f --allow-unauthenticated python3-venv

RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache wheel && \
    pip3 install --no-cache setuptools_scm

COPY package /package/

RUN cd package/ && \
    pip install . && \
    cd .. && \
    rm -r package/

COPY app/requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

As you can see I need to work a bit around our proxy server to get to the ubuntu repositories.

I run the "podman build ..." always as root and also the app inside is supposed to run as root.
However I get this strange error:

```
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 14378 files and directories currently installed.)
16:45:07  Preparing to unpack .../python3.8-venv_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
16:45:07  Unpacking python3.8-venv (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2) ...
16:45:07  dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3.8-venv_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
16:45:07   error setting timestamps of '/usr/share/doc/python3.8-venv.dpkg-new': Permission denied
16:45:07  Selecting previously unselected package python3-venv.
16:45:07  Preparing to unpack .../python3-venv_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
16:45:07  Unpacking python3-venv (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
16:45:07  dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-venv_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
16:45:07   error setting timestamps of '/usr/bin/pyvenv.dpkg-new': Permission denied
16:45:07  Errors were encountered while processing:
16:45:07   /var/cache/apt/archives/python3.8-venv_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2_amd64.deb
16:45:07   /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-venv_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
16:45:07  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
16:45:07  Error: error building at STEP "RUN apt-get install -y -f --allow-unauthenticated python3-venv": error while running runtime: exit status 100
```

I've no explanation why this happens or cause ? There is no SELinux nor AppArmor active ...
I even had a "RUN id" inside the Dockerfile to verify being root.

Any ideas ?

Comment: For many uses, you don't need a virtual environment in Docker, since the image itself has an isolated Python installation.  Does it work if you just outright skip all of the `apt-get` calls and `python3 -m venv`, and just `pip install` directly into the "system" Python?

Comment: Well skipping the `apt-get` part did work indeed. But now I'm facing the problem that the python libs seem too old for the app to run. However, the really strange thing is, if I create a running container from "python:3-ubuntu20.04" and log into it (as root) I can execute all the steps as described in my Dockerfile without any problems ? But using "podman build ..." fails.